# Solve the ODE $4y''\sqrt{y}=9$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be a solution to the ODE $$\begin{cases}4y''\sqrt{y} = 9\\ y(0)=1\ ,y'(0)=3\end{cases}$$

then $y(\frac{28}{9})$ is equal to -

1. 14
2. 15
3. 15
4. 17
5. none of the above.

I tried solving it by reducing its power or by substitution but I got nowhere. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $y'$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

$$2y''.y' = 9 \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

So

$$y'^2 = 9\sqrt{ y }+C$$

Comment: I hope my account won't be closed for 60 days.

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid penalties for answering poor questions, don’t answer poor questions, don’t admit you know this is a poor question and you answered it anyway…

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just gave a hint. Unfortunately i cannot delete it from mobile.

Comment: That is one big hint.